# How to separate a scope JavaScript scope to multiple files (Ubuntu JS scopes)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, scopes

I'm developing a simple web search scope (since weridly enough I couldn't find one). anmd after creating the POC I noticed the the main JavaScript file is quite large and complicated.

is there any way to separate the main file to multiple files? I've tried with the Node.js require but all I get is an error that it can't find the module :

```
var templates = require('./templates'); // in order to include templates.js
```

All I get in result is:

```
module.js:338
   throw err;
   ^

Error: Cannot find module './templates'
```

Anyone knows how to include a JS in the main scope JS file?

Comment: The convention here is different than other places.  You don't put [solved] into the title and you don't put the solution in your question.  If you solve the problem yourself, then you post an answer with the solution you found on your own and then, after some period of time has passed, you can even accept your own answer as the best answer by clicking the green checkmark next to your answer.   The notion of "solved" is indicated by an accepted answer with the solution in it.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 , i`m a little new for (actually posting on)  stack overflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

It seems that the answer was quite simple the "included" js file need to be under the **node_modules** directory and the require should not include current directory prefix ("./").
In other words the fix was to move the templates.js file under node_modules and change the code to  :

```
var templates = require('templates.js');
```